# Stop CSS * from inheriting a specific element and its children

Tags: css

I know there is many questions about CSS inheritance but none of what i saw are my case.

I'm building a widget that's going to be used by websites that i don't control.

Some of these website have horrible CSS rules, like:

```
*{
 color:green;
 font-size:20px;
}
```

As you see, this is going to be applied on all my widget's elements.

```
<div class="mywidget">
 Hello <b>World</b>
 <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>

<style>
.mywidget{
 color:brown;
 font-size:15px;
}

.mywidget span{
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
```

Even if i try to re-apply css to `mywidget`, the `<b>` and `span` tags won't change because of the previous `*` css rule, Ofcourse the solution would be to make a ton of CSS rules for every tag that i have which i don't appreciate.

Any CSS or Javascript solutions are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can beat `*` at its own game by using it yourself to reset all [inheritable properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html):

```
.mywidget * {
    color: inherit;
    *color: #000; /*include this line only if you need IE7 support */
    font-size: 100%
}
```

After that, add all your CSS for `.mywidget` and the elements inside it as you normally would.

Comment: I'd use `color: inherit; font-size: 100%`

Comment: @BoltClock: I agree on the `font-size`, but IE7 makes me dubious to use `inherit`.

Comment: @thirtydot What if `mywidget` color is set to brown and contains `<b>` tag which should be brown but doesn't have a specific class, i guess it'll be black instead of brown (its parent).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.mywidget, .mywidget *{
 color:brown;
 font-size:15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd imagine there to be several solutions to this, the most direct would be to add !important to the property, which will overwrite default styles e.g.

```
font-size:15px !important;
```